# Is there any way to update the model in the view?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, model, view

I'm writing a project in mvc 3.

I want to set an object in a view using razor.
To get the value I did this: `@Model.UserName;` and I do get the user name.

My question is how can I set the user name. I want to do something like:     `@Model.userName="xxx";`

Thank in advance:)

Comment: Can you explain why is the -1 ?

Comment: It looks like youre mixing up razor mvc syntax with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what solved my problem:

In javascript:

```
 var jqvalue;
    .........
    .........
    $("#id").val(jqvalue);
```

In razor:

```
@Html.Hiddenfor(model => model.userName , new {@Id ="id"})
```

and all in the same view.

Answer (score 0):

at first you can't write any c# code in JS, I guess you are trying to change post  data in JS,
and after that when you submit your post request processed in server your action will get expected model

there is a solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("form").submit(function () {
            var form = this;
            form.UserName.value = "xxxxxx"
            form.submit();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: did I understand your question?

Comment: No, Then I could do this: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName)

Comment: Say I want to write href to a link

Comment: can you explain in more details what do you need for result

Comment: I just want to change the existing value to another value - in the view.

Comment: Without sending anything to anywhere.

Comment: do you try writr @Model.userName="xxx" in any part of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way:

```
@model MyModel

@{
    Model.Username = "xxx";
}
```

But I'm not sure why you want to do that.